# Uncovering tree nodes

Tags: beamer

Considering the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}    

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
      level 1/.style={level distance=12mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}} },
      level 2/.style={sibling distance=12mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}}},
      level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}}},
      semithick]

      \node[draw=none,text=red] {S}
      child[visible on=<2,3>] {node[draw=none,text=red] (a)  {A}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am getting an error if I specify slide range using comma `,` at `visible on` option. It works well if I specify the range using `2-3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the comma is interpreted as a separator between different options. When the value of a key you are setting contains a `,` you should protect it with `{` and `}`: in your case you should use `visible on={<2,3>}`.

In this case, looking at how the value is used, you should add braces also to the line containing the definition of `visible on`, like this: `visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},`.

Therefore a working version of you example is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
      level 1/.style={level distance=12mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}} },
      level 2/.style={sibling distance=12mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}}},
      level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm,every child/.style={edge from parent/.style={->,solid,draw=blue}}},
      semithick]

      \node[draw=none,text=red] {S}
      child[visible on={<2,3>}] {node[draw=none,text=red] (a)  {A}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```